# Trim a character on SQL

Tags: sql, trim, string-length, charindex, left-to-right

Hi everyone this is my first time that i asked something.

I have multiple codes on my db with numbers and '/', for example:

```
510325205
510325205/000/01
510565025-01
510565025-01/090/03
...
```

I need to trim the `/` - I need these results:

```
510325205
510325205
510565025-01
510565025-01
...
```

I already searched and tried this

```
left(code, charindex('/', code))
```

and it works for the codes with `/` in it, but the codes without `/` are excluded from the results.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please tag your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your try was very close.
**All you needed to add was -1.**

As you can see the explanation for the left() function:

> The LEFT() function extracts a number of characters from a string
> (starting from left): LEFT(string, number_of_chars)

With charindex() function you have told the left() function how many characters to take. By adding -1 to that you have removed the '/' sign because you have told the LEFT() function to take 10 characters and not 11(for example) because 11th character is '/'.

```
select left('510325205/000/01',charindex('/','510325205/000/01')-1)
```

or because you have column named code

```
select left(code,charindex('/',code)-1)
```

If you have values without / you can use this:

```
select case when charindex('/',code_c)-1  = -1
            then 
            code_c
            else
            left(code_c,charindex('/',code_c)-1) 
            end RESULT
from test
```

OR

```
select left(code_c,iif(charindex('/',code_c)-1 = -1, len(code_c), charindex('/',code_c)-1)) 
from test
```

[Here is DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=adadad303691211e3fcd3852aae747d3)

Comment: OK it works but now i only see the codes that are being trimmed, i want to see also the codes that aren't being trimmed

Comment: Hi @Rj.27, I have updated my answer...